# ReduxForm is not re-rendering on button click

Tags: redux-form

I have a simple react-redux-form, upon button click state changes but the component is not re-rendering. Here is the sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-initialize-from-state-7th7q.

if you check the code, it has two buttons I am trying to render the button based on a property value of initial value. but it not working.

Comment: Will you explain better? When you click "Load account" in the sandbox, the form `initialValues` are set and the button "test" is rendered correctly in base on the condition. What you want to implement exactly?

Comment: Hi @Dario, if you see on click of the test I am changing age from 42 to 32 and the test button not should be visible. but it is not doing.